# Jquery Object array accessing in $.each loop

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm tying to access a specific value in an object array, but ONLY if

a) a specific user ID value is stored in `response.feed.data`

b) the key `story` exists

I've been playing around with $.each loops but I'm still sort of confused about accessing values inside nested objects, I'm doing SOMETHING wrong because the value is coming back as undefined no matter how I try to access it, [index].story currently just logs the same array of objects stored in `response.feed.data`

```
$.each(response.feed.data, function(key, index){
  if([index].id == "USER ID"){
    if([index].story){
        console.log([index].story);
    }

}
```

Comment: try `if($(this).id ==="USER ID")` what exactly is `[index]`? I doesn't look right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` will store the position of that specific `key` inside `response.feed.data`. So you can't access `index.story`. Instead you will have to access it from `key` if its present inside `key`.

Comment: That makes sense. So if I'm understanding correctly, to Iterate through an array inside an object I would require another each loop nested inside the above one, correct?

Comment: Using `$.each` you are iterating through the array `response.feed.data`. If you have an array within `response.feed.data`,then you will have to use nested  each loop.

Answer (score 0):

in $each loop, 1st parameter is your index and 2nd parameter is your element.

so you can access your element like below in your example

```
$.each(response.feed.data, function(key, index){
  if(index.id == "USER ID"){
    if(index.story){
        console.log(index.story);
    }

}
```

but follow the best practice and try to put meaning full name. so instead of index you can use item or element as a variable name.